# vb.net access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, dao

I am trying to read fields from a query into a text string arrary.  In vb6 I can simply declare the array and then read the fields into it without it caring what type of values are in it.  Now when I try to do that same thing I get an *"unable to cast com object of type 'dao.fieldclass' to type 'system.string"*.  Do I need to read the field value into a seperarte variable and then convert it to a string? The `seqNum` is what I am having the problem with

```
Public dbEngine As dao.DBEngine
Public db As dao.Database, recSet As dao.Recordset
dbEngine = New dao.DBEngine
Dim seqNum As Long
scExportTemplatePath = "M:\robot\scTemplates\"
db = dbEngine.OpenDatabase(scExportStuffPath & "scExport.mdb")
tsOut = fso.CreateTextFile(wildePath & dte & "-" & fle.Name & ".csv", True)
With recSet
    .MoveFirst()
    Do While Not .EOF
        seg = .Fields("segmentID")
        If seg <> segHold Then
            seqNum = 1
        End If
        arrOut(0) = .Fields("jobnum_AM")
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: You appear to be writing a recordset to a text file, do you need to do this record by record?

Comment: yes, I am reading record by record to write to the text file, this needs to be done this way because I will  be performing some calculations that will be dependant on what the previous record contains

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems with this code. In addition to the points mentioned by Jeremy:

1. What was `Long` in VB6 is now `Integer` in VB.NET. `Long` is a 64 bit integer now.
2. Use `System.IO.Path.Combine` in order to combine path strings. `Combine` automatically adds missing backslashes and removes superfluous ones. `Path.Combine(scExportTemplatePath, "scExport.mdb")`
3. The `Field` property does not have a default property any more. Non-indexed properties are never default properties in VB.NET. Get the field value with `.Fields("segmentID").Value`.
4. Convert its value to the appropriate type: `seg = Convert.ToInt32(.Fields("segmentID").Value)`
   Note: VB's `Integer` type is just an alias for `System.Int32`.
5. You are always adding to the same array field. I don't know exactly what you have in mind. If you want to add one field only, you could just use a `List(Of String)`. If you are adding several fields for each record, then a `List(Of String())` (i.e. a list of string arrays) would be appropriate. Lists have the advantage that they grow automatically.

```
Dim list As New List(Of String())
Do While Not .EOF
    Dim values = New String(2) {}
    values(0) = Convert.ToString(.Fields("field_A").Value)
    values(1) = Convert.ToString(.Fields("field_B").Value)
    values(2) = Convert.ToString(.Fields("field_C").Value)
    list.Add(values)
    recSet.MoveNext()
Loop
```

But it is more comprehensible, if you create a custom class for storing your field values:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} ({2})", user.FirstName, user.LastName, user.DateOfBirth)
```

... reads much better than:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} ({2})", values(0), values(1), values(2))
```

---

In VB.NET you have other possibilities to work with databases:

```
Dim list As New List(Of String())
Using conn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection( _
        "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=MyPath\MyDb.mdb")
    Dim sql = "SELECT myStuff FROM myTable"
    Dim command = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
    conn.Open()
    Using reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            Dim values = New String(reader.FieldCount - 1) {}
            For i = 0 To reader.FieldCount - 1
                values(i) = Convert.ToString(reader.GetValue(i))
            Next
            list.Add(values)
        End While
    End Using
End Using
```

Note that the `Using` statement closes the resources automatically at the end. Even if an error occurs and the code is terminated prematurely.

---

In VB.NET you can write to files like this (without using fso, which is not .NET like)

```
Using writer As New StreamWriter("myFile.txt", False)
    writer.WriteLine("line 1")
    writer.WriteLine("line 2")
    writer.WriteLine("line 3")
End Using
```

Comment: thank you, this is very helpful, i especially like how you gave me specific's with my code, but what if I wanted to read through a query that already exists in my db so that i don't have to write the SQL in my code?

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM myQuery`

Answer (score 1):

1) You dont show how you open the Recordset, eg:

```
Set recSet = db.OpenRecordset("query_name or SQL")
```

2) You dont have a .MoveNext in the While Loop:

```
With recSet
 .MoveFirst()
  Do While Not .EOF
  seg = .Fields("segmentID")
    If seg <> segHold Then
     seqNum = 1
    End If
    arrOut(0) = .Fields("jobnum_AM")
    .MoveNext()
  loop
```